# keyboard.is_pressed not detecting a keypress used for a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I encountered this problem after trying to make this program user friendly and able to work properly.
I am new to the keyboard library and have already changed the key to see if the program works.
I use the german qwertz keyboard, perhaps there could be a problem.
The function keyboard.is_pressed is used through a while loop, that should if it worked stop the loop if the key is pressed.I try to make an mouse tracker that tracks every click.
here is the code:

```
import pyautogui as pog
from pyautogui import *
import time
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
from pynput.mouse import Listener
time.sleep(2)

list = []
def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)

def start():
    start_zeit = time.time()
    return start_zeit

def stop():
    stop_zeit = time.time()
    pos = pog.position()
    
    global ans
    ans = pos
    return ans


def check_until_mouse():
    clicke = False
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 0.4 and clicke == False:
        while clicke == False:
            check = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
            if check < 0:
                stop = pog.position()
    while time.time() - start_time >= 0.4:
        w = "w"
    return stop
            

def aufnehmen_start():
    print("")
    time.sleep(2)
    

def aufnehmen():

    while keyboard.is_pressed("a") == False:
        list.append(check_until_mouse())


choice = input("Möchtest du aufnehmen(a) oder abspielen(ä)")
if choice == "a":
    print("ok")
    aufnehmen_start()
    print("los!")
    aufnehmen()


elif choice == "ä":
    print("ok")


print(list)
```

it is in german but basically it tells just the user what to do,
but currently it hasno real options other than pressing a to choose to record.

I expected that the while loop would stop the function and go on with the execution.

Comment: You never reassign `clicke`, so `while clicke == False:` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.